# Create a timer inside a Push Notification IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I know this question was already asked but it was an older question and things may have changed. 
Basically I want to create a push notification with a timer in it similar to how the clock app on the iPhone does when you snooze an alarm. 
[image]

Comment: You can't. You aren't Apple.

Comment: @Paulw11 Would sending a background update notification which then schedules a local notification in your app be able to pull something like this off?